# Indent a paragraph - all lines but the first

Tags: bibliographies, cross-referencing, paragraphs

I have multiple paragraphs in a chapter. I want to indent all but the first lines each. Is there any way to achieve this?

I tried \begin{hangparas}{1em}{1} but this will indent all but the first lines in the section (see capture).

I know that a proper bibliography would solve this. Unfortunately, this is not an option anymore as my transcribing the references from Excel to LaTex/BibTeX would blow my time frame.

Thanks in advance. [image: Capture]

Comment: You could use a negative value for `\parindent` and combine it with `changepage`'s `adjustwidth` environment.

Comment: You can try something like `\hangindent=2em`.

Comment: If you provide a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/97512), we can investigate the problem better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `hangingparas` environment – however this environement can't contain any sectioning command, so you may have to insert it multiple times:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hanging}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{chapter}{5}
\section{A First Section}
\begin{hangparas}{2em}{1}
    \lipsum[1-5]
\end{hangparas}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It worked but I had to insert it before every item as I was working with a lot of sections. 


But the file looks great now - worth the hustle.

I appreciate your input!